# Set allowed_domains per starter_url in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Is there any way to set allowed_domains per start_url? For each url in start_urls I want to restrict crawling to the domain of that url. Once a site has been crawled I would need that domain to be removed from allowed_domains. I guess one way would be to dynamically add / remove urls to allowed_domains?

Related question: [Crawl multiple domains with Scrapy without criss-cross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316900/crawl-multiple-domains-with-scrapy-without-criss-cross)

Comment: What have you tried? it's possible to implement a __init__() method that does that, yes.

Comment: I need the change to occur after each start_url, with associated crawls, has been processed. Wouldn't __init__ be called only once when the spiderclass is instanciated? Just to clarify, I will have multiple start_urls fed from a mysql db to a single spider instance.

Comment: Is there a way to use the current start_url in a rule?

Comment: Seems to me you need to run 3 spider instances, each one with it's `allowed_domains`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Where did you get 3 spider instances from? I have hundreds of urls that will be fed to start_urls so I don't see how 3 instances with their own static allowed_domains is going to help?

Comment: Sorry, I meant seperate spiders, I don't know where that 3 came from :)`OffsiteMiddleware` creates the domain regex when the spider is opened. So I don't think you'll be able to restrict crawling for the requests each start URL triggers, at least not with the builtin middleware. You could write a custom middleware that checks in `process_spider_output` what `Request`s are generated, if they match the response domain

Comment: Are you able to provide some example code for this? Appriciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, checking that spider `Requests` output for each response are for the same domain as that very response (warning: not tested):

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.utils.httpobj import urlparse_cached

class CrissCrossOffsiteMiddleware(object):

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        domainr = urlparse_cached(response.url).hostname
        for x in result:
            if isinstance(x, Request):
                if x.dont_filter:
                    yield x
                else:
                    domaino = urlparse_cached(x).hostname
                    if domaino == domainr:
                        yield x
            else:
                yield x
```