# Crawling domains serially with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have sites in a DB I want to crawl serially, i.e:

1. Add domain to allowed domains list (should be empty).
2. Add this domain to request (adding `http://` to it works perfectly).
3. Crawl the request, regarding the allowed domains.
4. Advance to next domain, add only it to allowed domains list. It will be the only one there, so no criss-cross will happen. Note: the [criss-cross question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316900/crawl-multiple-domains-with-scrapy-without-criss-cross) didn't help me, but maybe I'm missing something...
5. Crawl this request.
6. Finish all domains I have - serially.

What I have achieved so far is to crawl the domains, it does great work, it crawls the request perfectly.
The ONLY problem I have is that the `allowed_domains` seems not to update, it crawls all sorts of sites.

I set `DEPTH_LIMIT=1` so it won't be an infinite crawl and I also added DF crawl and not BF crawl:

```
DEPTH_LIMIT= 1
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
```

Here is the code of my spider (just the beginning; as you don't really care about my item processing...) :

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from company.items import CompanyItem, UrlItem
from urlparse import urlparse
import MySQLdb
import json


class RecipeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "company"

    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=(), tags=('a', 'link', 'li' 'area')), callback='extract_raw_recipe', follow=True),)

    def start_requests(self):
        # print "before sources"
        sources = self.get_allowed_domains()
        dummy_tuple = (long(len(sources) + 1), u'dummy', None, None, None, None, None, 0L, long(len(sources) + 1),)
        final_sources = sources + (dummy_tuple,)

        for source in final_sources:
            self.allowed_domains = [str(source[1])]
            url_string = str("http://" + source[1])
            self.start_urls = [url_string]
            self.update_running_source(source)
            yield Request(url_string, self.extract_raw_recipe)
    ### start_requests()

    def extract_raw_recipe(self, response):
        pass
```

The code of `extract_raw_recipe` has NO requests or parsing the next url, it just works, so no need to edit it. But if I need to add something there, tell me, because maybe this is the missing link. The current code adds a dictionary to an item and then puts this item in the DB.

**So in conclusion**: what do I need to add to make it filter domains every time it crawls the request?

Please let me know if there's a need to provide any more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to take a completely different approach.  Create a queue in your database of domains that need to be crawled (based on whatever criteria you want) then pick one domain to crawl and initialize the spider with the relevant domains in the `allowed_domains` list.  Once the spider is finished, re-start another crawl for the next domain.  Repeat until all domains in the queue are complete.

This will give you significantly more control over the entire process (eg. re-queue failed crawls, cancel problematic crawls and move-on without losing progress, crawl multiple domains at once with no "cross-talk", etc.)  If you plan on expanding this, it will also allow you to do things like custom settings (eg. USER_AGENT, DUPEFILTER, DOWNLOAD_DELAY), or custom rules on a per domain basis, significantly expanding the spider's usability.

---

If that's not an option, you can reset your `allowed_domains` list.  There's some issues with doing this, but first some background on Scrapy's offsite filtering.

The `OffSiteMiddleware` is responsible for compiling the lists of allowed domains based on `allowed_domains`.  It utilized a regular expression for this, which is compiled only once when the spider is started (using the `spider_opened` signal).  Updating the variable `allowed_domains` will have no effect on the spider unless you also force the `OffSideMiddleWare` to re-compile its regular expression.

The following method (placed in your spider) should be usable for replacing your `allowed_domains` with a new list:

```
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite import OffsiteMiddleware

def change_allowed_domains(self, allowed_domains):
    self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains

    for middleware in self.crawler.engine.scraper.spidermw.middlewares:
        if isinstance(middleware, OffsiteMiddleware):
            middleware.spider_opened(self)
```

*This will reset the `domains_seen` `set()` that the `OffsiteMiddleware` uses, so keep that in mind if you use it for anything else.*

So, taking a second to absorb all of that, a problem starts to surface: your current method of changing the `allowed_domains` as you queue each domain in `start_requests()` will not work, as the `Spider` class only keeps track of one `allowed_domains` regular expression (which isn't associate with request/response objects at all).  If you queue twenty requests to different domains (altering the `allowed_domains` list each time) before the spider starts crawling, it will use the most recently compiled regular expression (that is, the `allowed_domains` for the last-queued domain).

To overcome this, you would need to either crawl all requests for one domain, write your own `OffsiteMiddleware` with slots, and have it handle all the filtering.  Or you could create a differed to add the next domain to the list only once all requests in queue are done, and all slots in the downloader are empty (likely via checking `self.crawler.engine.slot.inprogress` and `self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler).

Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry, only now had time and resources to read your answer.
Wow, it gave me a lot to think about and to consider, thank you so much, will try it and update.

Comment: Tried it, it worked great to separate the requests and to let scrapy handle each site as a separate thread.